# How to set up subdomains correctly in docker nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, subdomain, nginx-config

I am trying to set up subdomains to separate the back-end and front-end sides:

- api.domain.com (back-end)
- app.domain.com (front-end)

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  gateway:
    container_name: ws-gateway
    build:
      context: gateway/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    container_name: ws-api
    build:
      context: api/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
```

This is my gateway Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine

COPY ./conf.d/api.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

WORKDIR /app
```

Configuration file "api.conf":

```
server {

    listen 8082;
    listen [::]:8082;
    server_name api.mydomainname.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass       http://api;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

I specified to listen on port 8082, specified the server name, but that doesn't work.

When I try to go to the `api.mydomainname.com` the server gives an error "[This site can’t be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFdOn.png)". But if I specify the port `mydomainname.com:8082`, [then it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgVzt.png):

Comment: It's confusing that you change both the hostname and the port number when you try. Does `api.mydomainname.com:8082` work (this is what you have in your nginx config). DNS also needs to be set up to resolve the api.mydomainname.com hostname. Have you done that?

Comment: @HansKilian If you mean writing A type record for subdomains in dns, then yes.

Comment: which port is `api` running on?